# Converting pixels into wavelength using 2 FITS files

Tags: python, numpy, astropy, fits

I am new to python and FITS image files, as such I am running into issues. I have two FITS files; the first FITS file is pixels/counts and the second FITS file (calibration file) is pixels/wavelength. I need to convert pixels/counts into wavelength/counts. Once this is done, I need to output wavelength/counts as a new FITS file for further analysis. So far I have managed to array the required data as shown in the code below.

```
import numpy as np
from astropy.io import fits

# read the images 

image_file = ("run_1.fits")
image_calibration = ("cali_1.fits")

hdr = fits.getheader(image_file)
hdr_c = fits.getheader(image_calibration)

#   print headers
sp = fits.open(image_file)
print('\n\nHeader of the spectrum :\n\n', sp[0].header, '\n\n')

sp_c = fits.open(image_calibration)
print('\n\nHeader of the spectrum :\n\n', sp_c[0].header, '\n\n')

# generation of arrays with the wavelengths and counts
count = np.array(sp[0].data)
wave = np.array(sp_c[0].data)
```

I do not understand how to save two separate arrays into one FITS file. I tried an alternative approach by creating list as shown in this code

```
file_list = fits.open(image_file)
calibration_list = fits.open(image_calibration)


image_data = file_list[0].data
calibration_data = calibration_list[0].data


# make a list to hold images
img_list = []
img_list.append(image_data)
img_list.append(calibration_data)

# list to numpy array
img_array = np.array(img_list)

# save the array as fits - image cube
fits.writeto('mycube.fits', img_array)
```

However I could only save as a cube, which is not correct because I just need wavelength and counts data. Also, I lost all the headers in the newly created FITS file. To say I am lost is an understatement! Could someone point me in the right direction please? Thank you.

I am still working on this problem. I have now managed (I think) to produce a FITS file containing the wavelength and counts using this website:

https://www.mubdirahman.com/assets/lecture-3---numerical-manipulation-ii.pdf

This is my code:

```
# Making a Primary HDU (required):
primaryhdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(flux) # Makes a header # or if you have a header that you’ve created: primaryhdu = fits.PrimaryHDU(arr1, header=head1)
# If you have additional extensions:
secondhdu = fits.ImageHDU(wave)
# Making a new HDU List:
hdulist1 = fits.HDUList([primaryhdu, secondhdu])
# Writing the file:
hdulist1.writeto("filename.fits", overwrite=True)

image = ("filename.fits")
hdr = fits.open(image)
image_data = hdr[0].data
wave_data = hdr[1].data
```

I am sure this is not the correct format for wavelength/counts. I need both wavelength and counts to be contained in hdr[0].data

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with spectral data, it might be useful to look into [specutils](https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html) which is designed for common tasks associated with reading/writing/manipulating spectra.

It's common to store spectral data in FITS files using tables, rather than images.  For example you can create a table containing wavelength, flux, and counts columns, and include the associated units in the column metadata.

The docs include an [example](https://specutils.readthedocs.io/en/stable/custom_loading.html#creating-a-custom-writer) on how to create a generic "FITS table" writer with wavelength and flux columns.  You could start from this example and modify it to suit your exact needs (which can vary quite a bit from case to case, which is probably why a "generic" FITS writer is not built-in).

You might also be able to use the `fits-wcs1d` format.

If you prefer not to use specutils, that example still might be useful as it demonstrates how to create an Astropy [Table](https://docs.astropy.org/en/stable/table/) from your data and output it to a well-formatted FITS file.

Comment: Thank you. I will have a look at the documentation.